# Conditional formatting Datatables to specific values in specific columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables, conditional-formatting

So I have the following template:

```
 {% load static %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivCSAT.net/npm/poppeCSAT.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/poppeCSAT.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>

 <div class="table-responsive-sm" style="overflow:scroll">
  <table class="table table-striped  table-bordered table-hover" id="example">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
    </tr>
    
</tbody>    
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>F</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

In columns C,D and E there are values displayed, being either: R, G, Y (red, green, yellow)

I have the following script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
     $('#example').DataTable( {
         initComplete: function () {
             this.api().columns().every( function () {
                 var column = this;
                 var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                     .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                     .on( 'change', function () {
                         var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                             $(this).val()
                         );

                         column
                             .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                             .draw();
                     } );

                 column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                     select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                 } );
             } );
         }
     } );

 } );
```

What I would like to do is turn the colour in each cell of columns C,D and E corresponding to the value that is found in the respective cells (R=red, G=green, Y=yellow).  I managed to make a working datatables by copying this script, but I have no clue how to implement the effective code that could make the table change the colours of the cell. Could someone please insert the code into the script and tell me what happened? Thank you all.

Comment: For clarification: When you say "the colour in each cell" - do you mean the cell's background color, or the color of the text?

Comment: @andrewjames I mean the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I know to do this is to use the `columnDefs.render` option, with some supporting CSS.

Here is the CSS, which in my case I included in the `<head>` section of the HTML page:

```css
<style>

  .bg_red {
    background-color: red !important;
  }

  .bg_yellow {
    background-color: yellow !important;
  }

  .bg_green {
    background-color: green !important;
  }

</style>
```

Note the use of `!important` in the CSS. This is a bit crude, but means this CSS overrides any row shading which may otherwise be applied by DataTables (e.g. the so-called "zebra stripes").

My test table is simply the following hard-coded HTML:

```html
    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>
        <thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>R</td><td>R</td><td>Y</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Q</td><td>X</td><td>G</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The DataTables function is as follows:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {
      columnDefs: [ {
        targets: [1, 2], 
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          var table = $('#example').dataTable().api();
          if (type === 'display') {
            var node = table.cell(meta.row, meta.col).nodes().to$();
            if ( data === 'R' ) {
              node.addClass('bg_red');
            } else if ( data === 'G' ) {
              node.addClass('bg_green');
            } else if ( data === 'Y' ) {
              node.addClass('bg_yellow');
            }
          }
          return data;
        }
      } ]
    } );

  } );

</script>
```

The `targets: [1, 2]` option means the render logic will only apply to the 2nd and 3rd columns in my table (the first column has an index of zero).

The `type === 'display'` option means we are only checking the display value of each cell. This [can be different](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) from the filter and sort values. In my simple case there is no difference, but it's a good idea to explicitly handle this.

The render logic adds the relevant class name to the table's `<td>` tag - which is part of the DOM, not a part of DataTables itself. This is why we access each cell's `node` object.

Using this `render` function also means the formatting will follow the data even when you sort and filter the table. Otherwise, the wrong cells would be highlighted after you sort/filter.